# É possível criar eventos individuais para as instâncias de um formulário no C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Suponhamos que eu tenha um formulário de cadastro de clientes:

```
        var frmCadCli1 = new frmCadastroCliente();
```

E que acabo de chamar esse formulário:

```
        frmCadCli1.Show();
```

Quando chamo esse formulário, imediatamente antes de ele ser mostrado o evento `Form_Load` é acionado.

Acontece que quero executar um `Form_Load` diferente para cada instância de `frmCadastroCliente`, por exemplo:

```
      private void btnConsulta_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        var frmCadCli2 = new frmCadastroCliente();
      }
```

Form load correspondente:

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          label1.Text = "Cadastro de Clientes";

        }
```

Depois:

```
      private void btnAltera_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        var frmCadCli3 = new frmCadastroCliente();
      }
```

Form load correspondente:

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          label1.Text = "Alteração de Cadastro";

        }
```

A razão pela qual gostaria de executar um `Form_Load`diferente para cada instância é que eu teria *diferentes instâncias com diferentes propósitos usando o mesmo design*.

Dessa forma eu poderia, por exemplo, usar o referido formulário como tela de cadastro de cliente, alteração de cadastro, ou mesmo como cadastro de fornecedores, apenas mudando as propriedades do formulário no `Form_Load`

Comment: Por que não passa um parâmetro no construtor e valida por ele? Ai tu usa só um `Form_Load()` chamando vários métodos diferentes.

Comment: Você diz o mesmo código do form load executando cada vez q abrir uma instancia nova, certo?

Comment: @Ricardo na verdade é exatamento o oposto, um form load diferente para cada instância.

Answer (score 2):

Você tem que passar como parâmetro mesmo. Até porque você vai precisar para salvar o cadastro correto.

```
    public Form(string Tipo)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

E passa na chamada o que você quer:

```
  private void btnConsulta_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    var frmCadCli2 = new frmCadastroCliente("Clientes");
  }

 private void btnAltera_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    var frmCadCli3 = new frmCadastroCliente("Fornecedores");
  }
```

Comment: Fiz o que você disse e não aconteceu nada, além disso, não entendi muito bem a diferença feita ao passar uma string como parâmetro na criação do formulário.

Comment: Como você está fazendo? A ideia é que você o que quiser para o outro form e lá você adequa da melhor forma. Eu coloquei um texto mas pode ser qualquer coisa que quiser, pensei no texto por conta do seu exemplo. Para complementar, seu Load ficaria assim:      public Form(string Tipo) { labal1.text = Tipo, InitializeComponent(); }